# Can't access my nodeJS web app hosted on AWS EC2 through browser

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, keystonejs

I have hosted a nodeJS application on AWS ec2 instance which I can access through ssh but not through my browser i.e, http.

There is no error logged on the console it only shows the following message in the browser:

> "unable to connect"

I am aware about security groups and checked them twice I've included http as well as https properly. Please help

[image: inbound (ingress) configuration]

Comment: Can you please attach your inbound (ingress) configuration?

Comment: Please check I've added it.

Comment: Can you post your NodeJS code? on which port you're listening? Plus can you try to Curl it?

Comment: It's a huge code so I can't really share the code I am listening on 4000 I'll try to curl and update you

Comment: Also check that you modify the correct Security Group which should be attached your EC2 instance

Comment: Thanks but  Renato Vassão's answer solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you configure a web server to direct the requests from the AWS URL to the nodejs application you are running?

Try checking out nginx (https://www.nginx.com/), its really easy and fast to cofigure.

Here is a minimal configuration template:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name <aws-url>;
  location / {
    proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:<node-port>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do I need ngnix on top of nodeJS server. I do not see any reason how that will help? Please explain a bit

Comment: You don't need it if you run your node server in port 80, but that is a high privilege port, so you can only do that if you run your application as root, which is not recommended. The recommended way is a web server, such as nginx, to create a proxy pass to your application.

Comment: Thanks a lot that resolved it. I was stuck at it for so long thanks again.